# Is this the right way to declare property wrapper in swift protocol?

Tags: ios, swift, combine, swift-protocols

Given this context where I have a class that implements a protocol's property where that property is prefixed with the property wrapper `@Published`.

```
protocol Manageable {

   var foo: String { get }
}

class Manager: Manageable {
    
    @Published var foo: String
}
```

I found myself in the following situation where I can't call the published property as `$` using the protocol.

```
let manager: Manageable = Manager()
manager.$foo // <== Error
```

Because we can't declare the `@Published` in the protocol I found myself in the position where I have to cast it to the class that implements it but is not what I want.
What I did to solve it were declaring a new publisher type property that returns the `$foo` property in its implementation as follow.

```
protocol Manageable {

   var foo: String { get }
   var fooPublisher: Published<String>.Publisher { get }

}

class Manager: Manageable {
    
    @Published var foo: String

    var fooPublisher: Published<String>.Publisher { 
        return $foo
    }
}
```

So now I call the publisher.

```
let manager: Manageable = Manager()
manager.fooPublisher // <== Works
```

I wonder if this is a proper way to solve this.
Have you guys found another way to do it ?

Comment: You could use `Published<String>.Publisher` as the type for your property in the protocol

Comment: I wouldn't put `foo` in the protocol, and I would make it `private` in the class.

Comment: Unfortunately Swift protocols don't support property wrappers on their properties. So yes, declaring a custom property with the property-wrapper's wrapped value type (`Published.Publisher` in the case of `@Published`) is as good a solution as you can get at the moment.

Comment: Thank you guys for your feedbacks. 
I think I will remove `foo` from the protocol and declare it private as @DanielT. suggested to only use the publisher.

Comment: I would also expose it as an AnyPublisher instead of a Published.Publisher. That way any publisher can implement it. The class conforming to the protocol might not want to use a @Published property.

Comment: A related scenario is that even if you don't need to use the $ property, any class designated as @MainActor ( to ensure SwiftUI updates occur on the main thread)  that implements the protocol will show warnings that the main actor isolated property cannot satisfy the protocols non isolated property requirement. Since isolated can only be applied to parameters, I see no way around this?